# Gitlab self hosted starts pinging different ips after installation (malware?)

Tags: gitlab

I have fresh installation of self hosted gitlab on digitaloceal ubuntu 20 droplet and I notice very strange stuff in production.log, it seems to be pingind different ips for no reasol, looks like malware.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are people/computers coming from outside, not your Gitlab trying to connect to outside IPs.

People are connecting to your front page ("/") and checking out "what's there" (and most likely deciding from there how and what kind of hacking tools or scripts to use to see if you're vulnerable).

Comment: you're right indeed. I whitelisted cloudflare ips and this rubbish is gone.